GAP orthogonal groups: Specifying the invariant bilinear form
If I read the GAP manual correctly, one should be able to specify the underlying invariant bilinear form, when constructing an orthogonal group. However, when I try something like:
mat := IdentityMat(3,GF(7));
GO(3,7,mat);

I get an error:
Error, canonical forms of <form> and <wanted> differ.

What am I missing here? I apologize in advance if this turns out to be a dumb syntactical problem.

This is a feature of the forms package. The problem is that the matrix you give is not equivalent over $GF(7)$ to the matrix used internally (but its negative is). If you use the negative -mat or work over the field with 49 elements (so you have a root of $-1$) it will work.

While everything Alexander writes is correct, let me say that this is not the intention of that feature: while the forms are not equivalent, they are similar, and hence have isomorphic orthogonal groups. I will log this is an issue in the forms package, and expect this to be fixed in GAP 4.13.1
